# Resuming hyperledger session using hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed a two [organization network](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html)

and I have submitted few transactions as well. Now if I stop my network is it possible to resume the network from where it was left.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to start and stop your Containers this way.  Fist you need to change to the your 'first-network' directory with a command similar to `~/fabric-samples/first-network`.

You can stop the Fabric with this command `docker-compose -f docker-compose-e2e.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml stop`

You can later resume the Fabric containers with this command, but be sure to be in the correct folder (first-network) `docker-compose -f docker-compose-e2e.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml start`

As you can see the BYFN Fabric and scripts use Docker Compose.  Docker and Docker Compose are useful tools to learn when working with Fabric.

Comment: @R Thatcher, I have executed the command which you have mentioned above and also issued `composer network ping -c admin@org1-network` to start my org1 network and similar for org2 but I see that there are few containers which are not started which is noticed by issuing command `docker ps -a`. How to start all containers related to hyperledger ?

Comment: If the other containers you are talking about are the Chaincode containers with long names including the Business Network name - then these will get started automatically the first time you "hit" the network with some request.